# Tomcat and Jetty on different branches

Tags: git, gradle, tomcat, jetty

Is it possible to have in one project on one branch Jetty, and on the second Tomcat?

I've created an application, and Google API enforce on me to use Jetty. I suspend this version and pushed it to Git repo for sake of portfolio to the first job.

I came back to the old version by creating a new branch from the old commit. I want to develop it, but my project is still working on Jetty regardless that I don't have any dependencies with jetty, nor tomcat excludes.

If it is possible, where I should search for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I pulled this branch separately from the repo, and now it works well.
But still, I would like to know why this happens